# OkHTTP AndroidBaseAdapter to ListView from data

Tags: java, android, listview, android-adapter, okhttp

I've set up okhttp to download data from my server and display it in normal text view.
But I would love to get it to ListView.

I know I need to have base adapter, some item layout and I need help with how to get it working with OKHTTP.

This is code that I use to download it, if you need anything else, please comment.

```
public class TaskAktualnosci extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            //*OKHTTP ponoć parametry dodaje do buildera*
       //     RequestBody parametry = new FormBody.Builder()
        //            .add("offset", "0")
         //           .add("limit", "50")
          //          .build();

            OkHttpClient klient = new OkHttpClient();
             final Gson gson = new Gson();


           Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("http://www.apirest.poligon.webimpuls.pl/v1/restapi/aktualnosci?offset=0?limit=50")
                   // .post(parametry)
                   .build();



            Response response = klient.newCall(request).execute();
            return response.body().string();



        }catch (Exception e){



            return null;
        }



    }


    @Override
    protected  void onPostExecute(String s){
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ciastko);
        textView.setText(s);
    }


}

}
```

I'm kinda new to android as whole and using Android Studio.

Can anyone explain it to me in normal way or show code snippet?

Comment: You don't need an AsyncTask to use OkHttp

Comment: I don't? How do I make it work then? I was getting network error when I tried else.

Comment: See "Asynchronous Get" -  https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes

Comment: I see. But is it bad to get using AsyncTask? Anyway, it's not the question though. The answear is good, but I  still don't get it completly, you can check it out too, please? This whole Adapters and Listitems and all that give me headaches :(.

Comment: You make a network request to download data in the background. When it finishes in the background task, you get a callback to the UI thread to update a List. You parse a string into Java objects. You add objects to an Adapter. A ListView displays Adapter data.

Comment: Allright, let's do this one stuff at the time. How can I get callback to the UI thread to update a List? I feel bad for not understanding an of your words, but I want to learn it.

Comment: Whether you follow the link I posted above, or use an AsyncTask, `onResponse` for OkHttp, or `onPostExecute(String s)` for AsyncTask is a callback. The background task has finished, and is now "calling back" to another thread to say it's work is completed. The parameter is the string data you downloaded, and then attempt to convert into a Java list to fill the Adapter and ListView

Comment: Any Tips on how to convert OKHTTP object into Java List? I saw there is GSON but it dosn't work with my code for some reason.

Comment: OkHttp doesn't convert anything, just downloads strings. It's up to you to use Gson appropriately. If you are going to be doing that, though, use the Retrofit library instead, which does exactly that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make your own adapter. I prefer to extend from BaseAdapter and create a own list item class:

```
class ListItem {
    private long mId;
    private String mContent;

    public ListItem(final long mId, final String mContent) {
        this.mId = mId;
        this.mContent = mContent;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return mId;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return mContent;
    }

}

public class adapter_akt extends BaseAdapter {
    private List<ListItem> mData = new ArrayList<>();

    public void setData(List<ListItem> data){
        mData = data;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public  ListItem getItem(int position){
        return mData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(final int position) {
        return getItem(position).getId();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null){
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent);
            ViewHolder h = new ViewHolder();
            h.textView1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            convertView.setTag(h);
        }

        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        ListItem item = getItem(position);
        holder.textView1.setText(item.getContent());

        return convertView;
    }

    public int getCount(){
        return mData.size();
    }

    private class ViewHolder{
        TextView textView1;
    }
}
```

then all u need is something to set your adapter to your ListView.

Your AsyncTask would look like:

```
public class Test1 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {
        //*OKHTTP ponoć parametry dodaje do buildera*
   //     RequestBody parametry = new FormBody.Builder()
    //            .add("offset", "0")
     //           .add("limit", "50")
      //          .build();

        OkHttpClient klient = new OkHttpClient();
         final Gson gson = new Gson();


       Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://www.apirest.poligon.webimpuls.pl/v1/restapi/aktualnosci?offset=0?limit=50")
               // .post(parametry)
               .build();



        Response response = klient.newCall(request).execute();
        return response.body().string();



    }catch (Exception e){



        return null;
    }



}


@Override
protected  void onPostExecute(String s){
    super.onPostExecute(s);

    List<ListItem> contentList = new ArrayList<>();
    /*
     her u need to read data from s to the list; 
     */

    MyListAdapter adapter = find();//here u need to get your Adapter, maybe its member of your fragment class
    adapter.setData(contentList);
}


}
```

Comment: Do I need to make layout for ListItem?

Comment: u can use android.layout.simple_list_item_1, i will update the answer

Comment: Yeah I still have trobule how to do this, I can't comprehend this all. I can't find some step by step guide or anything. Everything that I try Is giving me errors.

Comment: I will do this in about 2h, thanks for helping me I really appreciate this.

Comment: Sorry I'm late I had no internet for a while. Here's adapter which I made: https://codeshare.io/QDDVw, and It's giving me this error: "class  adapter_akt must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method getView(something) in adapter"

Comment: You have to implement `toString` if you want to use the simple list item layout

Comment: I see, there is a small error:
should be public View getView(final int position, final View v, final ViewGroup parent) { ... }
i will edit my answer

Comment: Why he needs to implement toString()? getContent already is String

Comment: Well, the fist part is working. I mean the ListItem. But I still get error in Adapter: http://imgur.com/a/wbaPW

Comment: i updated the adapter in the answer to match your code

Comment: Allright, thanks for the working adapter. It's looking great, but I still don't know what you mean with implementation in my activity. Hpw do I read data from s to list? Is there some function or something simpler? The second question how do I find adapter? Do I need to set something? I want to add all adapter is in other file. Many thanks for this, I start to catch up how it's all working.

Comment: I will try to work that out at weekend, i think the most of it we already have.